# adding link in link list- python

Tags: python

I tried to add link to link list but program is taking Nodes as an integer and not Node plz help me out in it

```
class Node(object): 

    def __init__(self, data): 
        self.data = data 
        self.next = None

class LinkedList(object): 

    def __init__(self): 
        self.head = None

    def push(self, new_data): 
        new_node = Node(new_data) 
        new_node.next = self.head 
        self.head = new_node 

    def add_link(self, new_link, after_link):
        new_link = Node(new_link)
        new_link.next = after_link.next
        after_link.next = new_link

    def printList(self): 
        temp = self.head 
        while(temp): 
            print temp.data, 
            temp = temp.next


llist = LinkedList() 
llist.push(20) 
llist.push(4) 
llist.push(15) 
llist.push(85) 

print "Given Linked List"
llist.printList() 
llist.add_link(35, 4) 
print "\nAfter adding Link new Linked List"
llist.printList()
```

The Error is on `new_link.next = after_link.next`

> AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'next'

Comment: `llist.add_link(35, 4)`, `after_link`  is an `int` (4) that's never converted to a `Node`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to just make a slight change in the add link function.

```
def add_link(self, new_link, after_link):
    new_link = Node(new_link)
    after_link=Node(after_link) 
    new_link.next = after_link.next
    after_link.next = new_link
```

This is because you are passing an integer(after_link) to the function and then using after_link.next which is not possible because after_link is an integer .So first you have to make a Node with its data as the after_link integer

Comment: Cool, but I need the next value of after_link when I use after_link=Node(after_link) the after_link.next value will be None

Comment: @ShaileshBhoyar So this afterlink is the 4 you pushed into the list using list.push(4)?If yes then please mention this in your question

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the object of type Node in which you will pass data and next

## sample code

`node_obj = Node(34,4)`
moreover in function `add_link(self, new_link, after_link)`,both parameters of new_link and after_link are of type Node